# E: Unable to locate package libproc-processtable-perl

Tags: package-management

I have this problem

```
$:~/media_build$ ./build
Checking if the needed tools for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS are available
ERROR: please install "Proc::ProcessTable", otherwise, build won't work.
You should run:
        sudo apt-get install  libproc-processtable-perl
Build can't procceed as 1 dependency is missing at ./build line 274.
```

But when I run it I get error

```
E: Unable to locate package libproc-processtable-perl
```

I also try

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

But without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for the `libproc-processtable-perl` ( [search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libproc-processtable-perl&searchon=names) ) shows that the package exists in all recent distributions, in the "Universe" repository:

```
Exact hits
Package libproc-processtable-perl

    trusty (14.04LTS) (perl): Perl library for accessing process table information [universe]
    0.50-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
    xenial (16.04LTS) (perl): Perl library for accessing process table information [universe]
    0.53-1build1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
    artful (17.10) (perl): Perl library for accessing process table information [universe]
    0.53-2build1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    bionic (18.04LTS) (perl): Perl library for accessing process table information [universe]
    0.55-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    cosmic (perl): Perl library for accessing process table information [universe]
    0.55-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
```

Do you have the "Universe" repository enabled?

Comment: It wasn't enabled, after enabling it, everything is ok.
Thank you